# How can I use Windows Containers for Software Testing?

Tags: windows, testing, docker, automated-tests, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to figure out how to do some software testing on a Windows 10 machine and I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible with Docker or some other technology. If anyone has any advice on if it is possible or not, and what technology I'll need to do it that would be great, more than happy to go of and investigate if I know I'm going in the right direction.

Essentially I want to build a container which uses my main Windows 10 installation as a basis but then has isolated containers which would:

- Look and behave as if they are part of the same Windows 10 install
- Be isolated from other containers also running in terms of applications and folder structure. I'd like to be able to start up an application in the container, give it access to folders on the main install as well as within the container and then have it pass out results back to the main Windows install.
- Have the ability to reset back to its original image state so when I launch the container at some point in the future, any applications or files that were installed into the container, are not there. I want to go back to the original state defined in the image (probably just a folder structure as any default applications would be installed on the base Windows install).

Does that make sense? I'd be interested to hear any thoughts on whether this is possible or not. I've been trying to do it for a few days without luck, using Docker, Docker-Machine, Hyper-V together with blogs/tutorials found online.

Thanks,

PH

Comment: Yes to all options. Please use a proper title that explains what you want. Is *what* possible? The question text sounds like a generic overview of containers. Shouldn't the title be "How can I use Windows 10 containers for testing?"

Comment: Creating VMs with snapshotting is your friend probably, but you could also try sandboxie: http://www.sandboxie.com

Comment: @BJBlack why? Containers already fulfill all requirements, indeed, that is the *definition* of a container. VMs are far heavier while sandboxie tries to fake containers, without any actual guarantees

Comment: I'll admit to not being that familiar with Windows containers, but Docker has extremely limited access to the rest of the system on Linux (except as explicitly allowed via -p, -v, and so on).  If windows containers can "Look and behave as if they are part of the same Windows 10 install," then alternative suggestions withdrawn.

Comment: @BJBlack that's not how Docker works, even in Linux. You can make a lot of modifications but these remain *inside* the container. Which is exactly what you want when testing

Comment: Testers _should_ want to catch...  I've known plenty that don't care.  Setting up a VM you can RDP into (and revert snapshots) is (in general) MUCH less initial work than writing a Dockerfile and capturing all that interface.  In the long term and for completeness perhaps not, but if OP can't get containers to behave, suboptimal is better than zero.  Sandboxie in particular is trivial to config.  And OP asked for any thoughts after all... :-)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is - no you can't use Windows 10 as a base. You can package Windows applications as Docker container images, but they need to be based from a server OS - either [Nano Server](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/nanoserver/) or [Windows Server Core](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/). You can run containers from those images on Windows 10.

Your containers will not look and behave as if they are just applications running on Windows 10. They are isolated units which look more like independent computers - every container will have its own (virtual) IP address and file system. You can integrate containers with your host though, by:

- publishing ports so network requests to the host get routed to the container, e.g. when you browse to http://localhost:8080 you could actually get a response from a container with port 8080 published;
- mounting part of the host's filesystem in the container using volumes, so your container can read and write to what it thinks is a local directory, but that's actually a mounted directory on the host, so it works like a network share.

Docker images are snapshots - when you run a container from the image it will have the state of the image when it was persisted. You can change things in the container but that will not change the image. Kill that container and start a new one from the same image, and it will have the original state.

We're at early stages with Docker on Windows, but the [Windows 10 quick start on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10) will get you started, or you can check my blog for [running IIS in Docker on a Windows Server 2016 VM](https://blog.sixeyed.com/1-2-3-iis-running-in-nano-server-in-docker-on-windows-server-2016/).

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback and suggestions so far. I'll investigate further now. @Panagiotis Kanavos - good point, I've renamed the post to hopefully give a better idea of the information I'm looking for.